# What is "Nav beacon" inventory item purpose?

Tags: x-rebirth

When I drop it in space it create some unselectable object, that emit light at intervals.
[image]

There is no in-game encyclopedia desription.
[image]

Is there any use for it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume the purpose of this thing is to help you see certain locations from a large distance. The orange blinking light can be seen from a bigger distance than space stations/ships. It could help a bit with navigation that way, like a little lighthouse in space.